# Can somebody explain this quote from movie Moneyball?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, moneyball

I watched movie Moneyball yet again and this quote from movie caught my attention. Can somebody explain this?

> You get on base, we win. You don't, we lose. And I hate losing, Chavy.
> I hate it. I hate losing more than I even wanna win. There is a
> difference. - Billy Beane

What is this difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is essentially [Loss Aversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion). The difference is that people respond more strongly to negative stimuli than to neutral or positive stimuli. So in this case, it is quite obvious that Billy Beane is reacting more strongly to losses (i.e. negative stimuli) than to wins (positive stimuli) and (implied) ties (neutral stimuli). From the Wikipedia link: "Some studies have suggested that losses are twice as powerful, psychologically, as gains."

See the Wikipedia entries on [*Loss Aversion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_aversion) and [*Neuropsychology of risk aversion*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_aversion_(psychology)#Neuropsychology_of_risk_aversion) in you're interested in learning more.